# Avoid using CROSS JOIN on my SQL query (too heavy)

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I am working on an SQL query in order to define customer types, the goal is to differenciate the old active customers from the churn customers (churn = customers that stopped using your company's product or service during a certain time frame)

In order to do that, i came up with this query that works perfectly :

```
WITH customers AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE(ord.delivery_date) AS date,
    ord.customer_id 
  FROM table_template AS ord
  WHERE cancel_date IS NULL 
    AND order_type_id IN (1,3) 
  GROUP BY DATE(ord.delivery_date), ord.customer_id, ord.delivery_date),

days AS (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM customers),

recap AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT  
            a1.date,
            a2.customer_id,
            MAX(a2.date) AS last_order,
            DATE_DIFF(a1.date, MAX(a2.date), day) AS days_since_last,
            MIN(a2.date) AS first_order,
            DATE_DIFF(a1.date, MIN(a2.date), day) AS days_since_first
        FROM days AS a1
        CROSS JOIN customers AS a2 WHERE a2.date <= a1.date
        GROUP BY a1.date, customer_id)
  )

SELECT * FROM recap
```

The result of the query : [image]

The only issue of this query is that the calculation is too heavy (it uses a lot of CPU seconds) I think that it is due to the CROSS JOIN.

I need some of your help in order to find another way to come with the same result, a way that doesn't need a CROSS JOIN to have the same output, do you guys think it is possible ?

Comment: Why don't you just use inner join, moving the `WHERE a2.date <= a1.date` into `ON a2.date <= a1.date`. I wouldn't expect much improvement though.

Comment: I think you want to join on `customer_id` , too.

Comment: "query timed out after 4 min" it's not super heavy, it takes too long to load when i inner join

Comment: If I understand your goal, you don't need the `days` calendar table. Just a window on `customer_id, delivery_date)` would suffice.

Comment: Hi @Hichhich, Can you provide the query which you are executing using the inner join?

Comment: Hi @PrajnaRaiT exactly the same as the one above, i juste change this line : CROSS JOIN customers AS a2 WHERE a2.date <= a1.date <===> INNER JOIN customers ON a2 WHERE a2.date <= a1.date

Comment: @wildplasser maybe a window on customer_id, delivery_date with a LAG function ? in order to take the previous value delivery_date of the customer and then after that i can do a date_diff between the delivery_date and the LAG column that i created ?

Comment: @Hichhich, It seems like you have used the wrong syntax for inner join. Can you change your syntax to `INNER JOIN customers as a2 ON a2.date <= a1.date` and try to execute the query?

Comment: Really sorry for the mistake @PrajnaRaiT it was indeed this syntax : INNER JOIN customers as a2 ON a2.date <= a1.date that i used, but the query took too long to load yesterday, but it seems like it was more of an internet issue because it looks like it works well, i still need to double check the numbers but thanks a lot !! Eventhough to be honest i have trouble understanding the meaning of the INNER JOIN on this particular case (ON a2.date <= a1.date)

Comment: Hi @Hichhich, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: Hello @PrajnaRaiT , sorry for the late answer, the change is working but i was waiting to see if i had some more issues with the query, and indeed it seems that even with the inner join instead of the cross, i still have the same issue after 2 days of working with the new query : "Your table exceeded quota for Number of partition modifications to a column partitioned table"

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned the problem of query taking a long time to load was because of the internet issue. Also, I will try to explain Inner Join further with a sample query as below:

```
SELECT distinct a1.id,a1.date    
FROM `table1` AS a1
INNER JOIN `table2` AS a2
ON a2.date <= a1.date
```

The INNER JOIN selects all rows from both the tables as long as the condition satisfies. In this sample query it gives the result based on condition `a2.date <= a1.date` only if date values in table1 are greater than or equal to date values in table2.

**Input Table 1:**

[image]

**Input Table 2:**

[image]

**Output Table:**

[image]